# Dot net version 4.7 application hosting in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I have .net framework 4.7 application. I want it to deploy in IIS. I have .net verion 2.0 and 4.0 installed.

Do I need to install the version 4.7 alone in my system? or anything do I need to install extra?

Comment: You have to install .NET Framework 4.7.

Comment: Any specific IIS version should I use for this?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/02/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-general-availability/ Only a few Windows releases are supported.